# android-studio, где нибудь есть что то вроде журнала изменений проекта?

Tags: android-studio

Нужно загрузить версию проекта трехдневной данности, откатив эти самые изменения за три дня. Использование Recent changes Alt+Shift+C не помогает, там изменения хранятся за несколько часов всего.

Answer (score 2):

Нажмите на вкладку **VCS** сверху. Затем нажмите **Local History**. Там вы сможете выбрать один из снапшотов вашего кода. Если вам нужно откатить весь проект, закройте открытые классы и выберите папку корня проекта, прежде чем заходить в папку **VCS**. Так же рекомендую [освоить Git](https://githowto.com/ru), т.к. это более гибкая система контроля версий, чем встроенная.

---

P.S. Там может не быть всех изменений, которые вы производили, если вы чистили кеш проекта.